# Strange behavior of dragLeave event on browsers

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer-11, draggable

I was working with drag Events on browsers using 'dragstart', 'dragleave' events. The behavior is very different in Internet Explorer 11 when one just adds a width property. As soon as a width property is specified for the elements, the `dragLeave` event starts firing and without it, it doesn't. Can someone explain why exactly two different behaviors are observed just because of a width property. This issue is specefically observed in IE11.

Here are two jsFiddles that differ only in their CSS: https://jsfiddle.net/fb5sp5yc/1  https://jsfiddle.net/f3ap2242/3. In other browsers(Chrome, Firefox), everything fires as expected.

HTML Body:

```html
<div id="d" draggable="true">MoveInMoveOut</div><br>
<div id="s" draggable="true">DragMe</div>
<select id=oResults size=30>
    <option>List of Events Fired
</select>
```

JS Code:

```js
function ShowResults() { 
    var oNewOption = new Option(); 
    oNewOption.text = event.type + "  fired by  " + event.srcElement.id;
    oResults.add(oNewOption,0);
}

var myDiv = document.getElementById("d");
myDiv.addEventListener('dragenter', ShowResults, false);
myDiv.addEventListener('dragleave', ShowResults, false);
```

CSS:

```css
#s {
    background-color: red;
    width: 200px; /*Only this property changes*/
}

#d {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 200px; /*Only this property changes*/
}
```

Comment: Seems like an IE-specific bug. It works fine in Edge, so I would just specify a width to make it work. Unfortunately that's the nature of IE these days. Even Microsoft has abandoned it for a new browser.

Answer (score 0):

In Chrome,if the width of s and d is more than the element's width then there will be a default overflow property, but IE it won't happen by default. I tried giving

`#oResults{
  overflow:visible;
}`

It worked fine for me, please try including this and test in IE.